# node js - sscanf throws type error when using the following format "P%fM%f"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use `sscanf` in node js.

I expect that:

```js
const sscanf = require('sscanf');
sscanf("P15.02M12.3", "P%fM%f");
```

would return `[15.02, 12.3]` but I'm getting an `Unknown type %fM` error instead.

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Don't know if that helps, but if you add an extra space before "M" then it works: `sscanf("P15.02M12.3", "P%f M%f")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve here. But I still would like a give it a try.

```
const sscanf = require('sscanf');
let result = sscanf("P 15.02 M 12.3", "%s %f %s %f");
```

Above code will output: `[ 'P', 15.02, 'M', 12.3 ]`.

This is what I thought you were trying to do. If this is not the response you expected and I'd suggest you add more details to your question.